# How do I add together Random Integers from a for loop with PHP

Tags: php, for-loop, random, sum, addition

I was messing around with PHP and I figured out how to list 5 random integers between 1 and 100 using a for loop:

```
for($row = 1; $row <= 5; $row++) { 
    echo rand(1,100) . "<br>";
}
```

I know that I can get the sum of random numbers by doing the following:

```
$sum = 0;
for($row = 1; $row <= 5; $row++) { 
    $sum += rand (1,100) . "<br>";

}
echo $sum;
```

But now I don't know how I can echo the rands to be seen as well. 
I want to be able to somehow combine the first piece of code and the second to get the list of random integers and their sum.

Comment: Initialize your sum variable with 0 before your loop. In your loop you simply add your current sum with the random value of the iteration and save it back in your sum variable.

Comment: Did none of the answers resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you're planning to reuse the data, store them in a variable.
You should be looking into array's here:

```
for($sum = 0, $row = 1; $row <= 5; $row++) { 
  $num = rand (1,100);
  $nums[] = $num;
  $sum += $num;
}

echo "the total sum is: '$sum' with the values of: '" . implode(', ', $nums) . "'.";
```

Or just loop through it:

```
foreach($nums as $value){
  echo $value, '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up using, and it worked! Thanks!

```
<?php 

for($row = 1; $row <= 5; $row++) { 
    $value = rand (1,100);
    echo $value . "<br>";   
    $sum += $value;
}

echo $sum;

?>
```